# Gitlab showing all target branch commits in new merge request

Tags: laravel, gitlab, codebase

I branched from develop while working on a project, and when I made a merge request, Gitlab is showing all the commits on branch develop, whereas I only made two commits on the branch itself. It is the same time even when I try from an entirely new branch or branch from master.

The person who is supposed to merge it has refused saying it can mess up the codebase. What can I do to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: We've been facing the same issue recently. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check "squash commits when merge request is accepted". Then, your branch will be merged with only one commit, keeping the branch tree clean.

Comment: I think what made Korlahawarleh exhausted is the commits should not contain all commits. It should only contain the last several commits.